# Unable to locate the pagination links when scraping a website using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm learning to use Selenium for web scraping. I have a couple of questions with the website I'm working with:

-The website has multiple pages to go over and I can't seem to find a way to locate the pages' paths and go over them. For example, the following code returns `link_page` as `NoneType`.

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league')
time.sleep(0.5)
results_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/span')
results_button.click()
time.sleep(3)

season_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/span/strong/a')
season_button.click()

link_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div/a[3]/span').get_attribute('href')
print(link_page.text)
driver.get(link_page)
```

-For some reason I have to use the `results_button` to be able to get the `href` of matches. For example, the following code tries to go the page directy (as an attempt to circumvent problem 1 above), but the `link_page` returns a `NoSuchElementException` error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/#/page/2')
time.sleep(3)

link_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]/a').get_attribute('href')
print(link_page.text)
driver.get(link_page)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the pages to go over them using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='RESULTS']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='2018/2019']"))).click()
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='active-page']//following::a[@x-page]/span[not(contains(., '|')) and not(contains(., '»'))]/..")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/2/', 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/3/', 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/4/', 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/5/', 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/6/', 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/7/', 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/8/']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```